# Cluster Analysis for mixed data and using a large sample

Tags: clustering, mixed-type-data

I wanna perform Cluster Analysis and I have Mixed data (a couple of dummy variables). I've found some information about Gower's distance, but when I tried to use it, R broke down (i guess) because I have a large sample size (almost 1,000,000). Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Begin with a subset first. To learn what works and what doesn't.

Don't immediately try to scale.

Also you don't need to use all your data. If you find patterns on a subset, these supposedly are still patterns on the entire data. The purpose of clustering is not to label each point a, b, c. But rather to find actionable patterns and regularities.